# How to increase the caption area for vaadin timeline

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

If I add too many/too long captions to a vaadin7 timeline, they will only be displayed partially (i.e. the part we have space for is displayed and the remainder is truncated) 
How can I increase this area in order to allocate enough space for all?

```
timeline.setGraphCaption(container, h.toString());
```

Comment: Do you want to add new line or create horizontal scrollbar? http://up.programosy.pl/foto/timeline.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these rules in your scss file:

```
  .v-timeline-widget .v-timeline-widget-modelegend{
    background: inherit;
  }

  .v-timeline-widget-legend-label{
    height: auto !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
```

Before:
[image]

After

[image]

3 points:

1. While these rules may not met criteria of well-written CSS or good practice rules (I am looking at you *!important*), they do the trick. Still, better approach would be to get your hand dirty by editing Vaadin Timeline addon sources.
2. As you surely noticed text background has changed. That's because we override default background which was designed for only one line (you should provide your own background image)
3. Bottom of the widget is cut off by few pixels. Well, the only way to fix it is to jump into DOM and css and try fix it. Doable but I haven't tried.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I still have two issues: 1, If I want to display a really long message, (>10 lines) the string still gets truncated. The other one is the issue you mention under point 3.